# how do I pass a string parameter to AWS lambda function from AWS API?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

```
public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    Hashtable<String, String> htAWSServices = 
            new Hashtable <String, String> (){{
                put("Compute","For Compute - please insert like Compute1/.../Compute6");
                put("Compute1","AWS Lambda(Compute)");
                put("Compute2","AWS EC2(Compute)");
                put("Compute3","AWS EC2 Container Service(Compute)");
                put("Compute4","AWS Lightsail(Compute)");
                put("Compute5","AWS Elastic Beanstalk(Compute)");
                put("Compute6","AWS Batch(Compute)");

                put("Analytics","For Analytics - please insert like Analytics1/.../Analytics8");
                put("Analytics1","AWS Athena(Analytics)");
                put("Analytics2","AWS EMR(Analytics)");
                put("Analytics3","AWS CloudSearch(Analytics)");
                put("Analytics4","AWS Elasticsearch Service(Analytics)");
                put("Analytics5","AWS Kinesis(Analytics)");
                put("Analytics6","AWS Data Pipeline(Analytics)");
                put("Analytics7","AWS QuickSight(Analytics)");
                put("Analytics8","AWS Glue(Analytics)");
            }};

    String stOutput = "";
    String stValue = htAWSServices.get(input);

    if (stValue == null)
        stOutput = "Hello from Lambda!, "+input+"!";
    else
        stOutput = "Hello AWS has "+stValue+"!";
    return stOutput;
}
```

Now do I pass the key values from API Gateway to the Lambda function?

Comment: A Lambda takes an event, a context and a callback. When hitting the API Gateway, you can add the parameters in the url, and those values become the event. An example would be `www.myendpoint.com/?input=myInput`.

Comment: I would suggest , create custom request class and mentioned all fields in that class.  Like Public class RequestClass { private String Compute; } Set all value to this class instead of passing in key value

Comment: Thanks @John. Now the problem is coming when I hit the URL with parameter. I used the pattern as you said, but it says {"errorMessage":"An error occurred during JSON parsing","errorType":"java.lang.RuntimeException","stackTrace":[],

Comment: Thanks @Vaibs.  This time it works without Custom class.

Comment: @BhaskarPal Can you mark this as answered?